# How to break out of the loop only if a certain case is met, but then continue the iteration?

Tags: python

I realize that the title may be somewhat confusing, so I apologize.

Basically, this is my code:

```
while i < 5:
   do stuff
   if i == 3:
      print "i is 3"
      break
```

Now all that sounds pretty simple, right? Except I don't really want to BREAK from the loop as much as I'd want it to start over again. So in this case the desired result would be to iterate through 1, 2, then when 3 break out, but then continue iterating with 4. How do I do that?

Comment: As Matthew points out, you can use `continue` instead of `break`. But since `continue` would be the last statement in the loop anyway, you can just delete your `break`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
while i < 5:
   do stuff
   if i == 3:
      print "i is 3"
      continue
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks. Will mark it as answer the moment I'm allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `break` use `continue`

Now, I pretty much never use continue as I find it is usually clearer to rework the code to avoid it. Of course that's really easy in this example, if you have trouble with a more complex example ask about that one.